Physical meaning of constant boundary condition
I am studying fluid-structure interaction (so, based on Navier-Stokes equations).
In particular, i read about the Stokes Paradox, that says that there is no solution to the 2D Stokes problem outside a body with constant boundary condition ($v_{fluid} = c$ on $\partial B$, with $c \in R^2 $ constant, and $B$ the body of the particle) on the particle and zero boundary condition at infinity.
So, I have this particle in a 2D fluid, and on its boundary i have constant boundary condition (given by the no-slip condition between the fluid and the solid).
My question is: how can i imagine this condition? Because i do not understand how the velocity can be constant on the body. Is it as if the solid has zero density, so it does not give any interaction? I am thinking this since i usually expect velocities' streamlines to bend around the body (this would mean not constant velocity on its boundary).
Can someone give me some kind of hint to better understand it?
